# Finding the next occurrence of a value in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Sorry in advance if this has already been covered.

I am working on a database which isnt particularly well structured but it is owned by a third party and cannot be changed.

I need some assistance with t-sql in find the next occurrence of a value within the table and return records based on the result. Let me first explain the data. I have simplified this to make it easier to understand.

```
Polref      Effective Date       Transaction Type     Suffix        Value
ABCD1       01/06/2010           New Bus              1             175.00
ABCD1       01/06/2011           Ren                  2             200.00
ABCD1       19/08/2011           Adjust               3              50.00
ABCD1       23/04/2012           Adjust               4              50.00
ABCD1       01/06/2012           Ren                  5             275.00
```

So if I ran my query for 2011, the code would need to return in this example rows with suffix 2,3 and 4. So what I have been trying to do is find the first suffix of a New Bus or Ren for the specified year and then finding the next suffix for a New Bus or Ren for the same polref and then using those two suffix values to limit my recordset. It aint working!!

I cant use MAX() as transactions for 2013 have already been added to the system to I would get more records than I actually need.

There result I should be expecting for this example data would be:

ABCD1       300.00

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To answer another question, If I select 2011 as my year to run the report, there should only be one New Bus or Ren transaction for 2011 so if its a New Bus transaction, the next main transaction will be a Ren, if its a Ren then the next main transaction will be a Ren. Again in my example below, if I run for 2011, it should find the Ren from 01/06/2011 so I want to return that Ren and the two Adjust records.

Sorry, I've not used this forum before so apologies if I was a little vague.

The table I am using has many polrefs so I need this code to calculate totals for all polrefs that fall within the date range. Some polrefs may only have one row, a New Bus, some will have many rows depending on how many adjustments have been made throughout the year of the policy

Comment: I can't understand what the output is that you are looking for. Please provide sample output.

Comment: Sorry, bit quick off the mark there. I need a row that has the Polref and a total of the values for the transactions between the last and previous renewals so in this case 300.00

Comment: What data type if Effective Date? And is another way to phrase your query - "Given an input year (and a particular client?) locate the earliest `New Bus` or `Ren` row, and return that row, and all subsequent rows up to, but not including, the next `New Bus` or `Ren` row"? - and if the first is `New Bus`, do we search for both `New Bus` and `Ren`, or just `New Bus`? (It would help if you'd re-read your question too, since you talk about clients, but no such columns exist)

Comment: And please, if you have more information to add, *edit* your question to include it - don't attempt to add lots of information in the comments.

Comment: Does this table only contain one `PolRef`, or does it contain many, and if so are we trying to compute the result for one `PolRef` or for all? Are suffixes monotonous with no gaps (within a `PolRef`)? I'll try to help, but you need to think carefully about all of the data and tell us what the actual rules are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

This query:

```
declare @t table (PolRef char(5) not null, EffectiveDate date not null,TransactionType varchar(10) not null,Suffix int not null,Value decimal(10,2) not null)
insert into @t (Polref,EffectiveDate,TransactionType,Suffix,Value) values
('ABCD1','20100601','New Bus',1,175.00),
('ABCD1','20110601','Ren',2,200.00),
('ABCD1','20110819','Adjust',3,50.00),
('ABCD1','20120423','Adjust',4,50.00),
('ABCD1','20120601','Ren',5,275.00)

;With StartTransactions as (
    select PolRef,Suffix,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolRef ORDER BY Suffix) rn
    from @t where TransactionType in ('New Bus','Ren')
), Periods as (
    select st1.PolRef,st1.Suffix as StartSuffix,st2.Suffix as EndSuffix
    from
        StartTransactions st1
        left join
        StartTransactions st2
            on
                st1.PolRef = st2.PolRef and
                st1.rn = st2.rn - 1
)
select
    p.PolRef,t2.EffectiveDate,SUM(t.Value) as Total
from
    Periods p
        inner join
    @t t
        on
            p.PolRef = t.PolRef and
            p.StartSuffix <= t.Suffix and
            (p.EndSuffix > t.Suffix or
            p.EndSuffix is null)
        inner join
    @t t2
        on
            p.PolRef = t2.PolRef and
            t2.Suffix = p.StartSuffix
group by
    p.PolRef,t2.EffectiveDate
```

Groups each set of transactions based on each successive `Ren` or `New Bus` transaction:

```
PolRef EffectiveDate Total
------ ------------- ---------------------------------------
ABCD1  2010-06-01    175.00
ABCD1  2011-06-01    300.00
ABCD1  2012-06-01    275.00
```

From that, it should be trivial to e.g. select out only the ones you're interested in from a particular year. But your question is still vague on some specifics, so I'm not taking it any further at this point.

Comment: Damien, thanks very much for your help, I have used your code as a basis and it works very well. I apologise for the vague nature of my post, you have helped out a great deal, cheers

Comment: @JulianSlaughter - no problem. Hopefully, next time you ask a question, you'll try to be *more* specific on the requirements. We love specificity. But it also helps if (as here) you've simplified the problem, you're specific on *how* the problem is simplified. Sample data is always good (as are sample results), but if you over simplify, we may assume too much.